# Pick out a number

Tags: javascript, args

i want my discord bot to only answer on a message that has 1-50 in args[2]. so of they pick a number between 1 and 50 it will answer. but if i put in something else, it shouldn't work. i have tried many different ways. here are some of them:

```
if (!message.content.includes(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50)) {
    message.channel.send("Error!") };
```

and:

```
if(!args[2] === 1-50) return message.author.send("Error!");
```

Comment: hi, maybe you need to use parseInt in your args[2], `const myNumber= parseInt(args[2]);`

Comment: if (x<1 || x>50) return .....

Answer (score 0):

For the first solution, message.content is probably a string so you should compare it to a string. That would be:

```js
if(!message.content.includes('1')) message.channel.send("Error!");
```

What you are also doing is giving the function 50 arguments but it only takes two. 
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes so that won't work.

For the second solution you are checking if a boolean is equal to -49 since the dash is a subtractions sign in js. I would change that to:

```js
if(parseInt(args[2]) < 1 && parseInt(args[2]) > 50) return message.author.send("Error!");
```

assuming that args[2] is numerical.